# how to specifiy web api route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call the api action method using `HttpClient`.
This is my api controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/OrganizationUnit")]
    public class OrganizationUnitController : ApiController
    {
        public IOrganizationUnitRepository OrganizationUnitRepository;

        [Route("{id}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(OrganizationUnit))]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
        {
            return Ok(OrganizationUnitRepository.Get(id));
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(OrganizationUnit))]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Ok(OrganizationUnitRepository.GetAll());
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(OrganizationUnit))]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAllOU")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAllOrganizationUnits()
        {
            return Ok(OrganizationUnitRepository.GetAllOrganizationUnits());
        }
}
```

Below is the Route config:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

And in the MVc controller I am calling this API, like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var organizationUnitUrl = Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httpRoute = "", controller = "OrganizationUnit" }, Request.Url.Scheme);
                string requestUrl = organizationUnitUrl.ToString() + "/GetAllOU";
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
                responseTask.Wait();
                var result = responseTask.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<OUWrapper>>();
                readTask.Wait();
                organizationUnitList = readTask.Result.ToList();
            }
        }
```

**I want to call the action `GetAllOrganizationUnits` which has `Route` specified as "GetAllOU".**
As you can see, I am appending the "GetAllOU" to the url when calling the api using `HttpClient`. I think there has to be a good way in which I can call this api without appending anything to URL. 
Is there a way where I can specifiy the Route "GetAllOU" and call the action?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please specify what you want to, its difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed webApi with MVC. You should not use RouteConfig until you understand what you are doing. I suggest go back to defaut RouteConfig values.

If this is mvc then you can use return `RedirectToAction("Action Name", "Controller Name");` method.

If this is web api you can call it by Postman program or within Action by

```c#
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage message = client.Get(_url);
```

This will only get response message. You should take this message and read it as string: `string json = message.Content.ReadAsString();`

Next you can convert json to object by NewtonsoftJSON package:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeObject>(json);
```

Comment: Yes I am using Web API with MVC and I don't get any issue calling other API actions like the one which takes id parameter or simple get method without any parameter. It is this particular GET method that has almost similar pattern with other GET method of without parameter. So I was trying to specify different Route for this method

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you, simple and easy way to services clients.

```
    private HttpClient _simpleserviceClient;

    private const string _getUri = "/ROUTE_TO_ACTION/{0}";
    private const string _postUri = "/ROUTE_TO_ACTION";

    public ReturnModel Postdata(SomeModel model)
    {
        var uri = string.Format(_postUri );
        var response = ServiceClient().PostAsJsonAsync(uri, model).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReturnModel>().Result;
        return result;
    }

    public ReturnModel getdata(int id)
    {
        var uri = string.Format(_getUri ,id);
        var response = ServiceClient().GetAsync(uri).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReturnModel>().Result;
        return result;
    }

    private HttpClient ServiceClient()
    {
        var client= _simpleserviceClient ?? new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("YOUR_BASE_URL_TO_API");   //"http://localhost:8080/"
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
    }
```